# Domain of `let` variables into `ask`

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know if `let` defined variables into an `ask turtles [...]` belongs only to each turtle in particular, that is, the pararell execution of `ask turtles [...]` is for the whole content or instructions into the brackets and, turtles are not executing the instructions into the [ ] at the same time.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of `let` is the immediate `[]` that it appears in. The `let` belongs to the scope, not to any agent. That is, it doesn't persist outside of the `ask`. Second, `ask` does not run each agent in parallel; it runs them sequentially, in a random order (since agentsets are not ordered). A good way to see this:

```
create-turtles 10
ask turtles [
  let id who
  show id
  set id "hi"
  show "hi"
]
```

Example output:

```
(turtle 6): 6
(turtle 6): "hi"
(turtle 9): 9
(turtle 9): "hi"
(turtle 0): 0
(turtle 0): "hi"
(turtle 7): 7
(turtle 7): "hi"
(turtle 8): 8
(turtle 8): "hi"
(turtle 5): 5
(turtle 5): "hi"
(turtle 4): 4
(turtle 4): "hi"
(turtle 2): 2
(turtle 2): "hi"
(turtle 1): 1
(turtle 1): "hi"
(turtle 3): 3
(turtle 3): "hi"
```

Does that answer your questions? If not, let me know and I am happy to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. Then, if I correctly understand I must not to be worried that an agent uses any let variables of another agent, isn't it?

Comment: That's right! As long as the `let` is inside the `ask` that is.